# Is it possible to have a DB uniqueness constraint across columns of two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I have a mysql DB with rails, and a column "shorthand" (string) that I'd like to make unique across multiple tables. Is there a way I can do this without making a third table?

```
Expression
id
shorthand
... 
etc

Variable
id
shorthand
...
etc
```

I want the values in the 'shorthand' columns of both tables to be unique between each other ie. a record shorthand value "xyz" in Expression would be rejected if a Variable with shorthand value "xyz" were to exist in the DB already.

Any thoughts appreciated, even "you have to use a third table" :)

Comment: You can't do this without third table, I think.

Comment: Trigger-based constraint will do it.

Comment: Put them in the same table, or use a third table plus triggers. Or use a mutual trigger kludge on `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this older article does exactly what you are looking for (simulating multi table constraints):
http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps180/Winter04/constraints.html

You might also like to investigate postgres `CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` using a function similar to the `check_nojoin()` function in the article.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createconstraint.html

Once you have the exact SQL you need you can put it in your rails migration with `execute "the required SQL"`

An alternative approach is to use a third table 'shorthands' with columns 'shorthand' and 'src'. Define shorthand as the unique primary key on that table.  On each of your other two tables define 'src' as a single char field defaulting to 'A' and 'B' on each table respecitively. Add a foreign key constraint on each of your two tables consisting of both 'shorthand' and 'src' and referencing table 'shorthands'. When inserting or updating rows in either of your  two tables you need to ensure the 'shorthands' table is updated either explicity as part of your transaction or via a trigger and set both 'shorthand', and 'src' to the respective table ie 'A' or 'B'.

What the foreign key constraints do is ensure that the shorthand value exists in the shorthand's table for the respective src table but because of the uniqueness constraint on just the 'shorthand' column in the shorthand's table if the other table has already defined the shorthand value a key violation will occur thus guaranteeing uniqueness across two (or even more) tables.

Whatever you do, it is best to put the referential integrity into the database, not in orm/active record validations.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example using a third table:

```
        -- TEMP SCHEMA for testing
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE shorthand
        ( shorthand varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , one_or_two varchar NOT NULL
        );

CREATE TABLE table_one
        ( one_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , shorthand varchar NOT NULL REFERENCES shorthand(shorthand)
                                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                                DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
        , etc_one varchar
        );

CREATE TABLE table_two
        ( two_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , shorthand varchar NOT NULL REFERENCES shorthand(shorthand)
                                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
                                DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
        , etc_two varchar
        );

        -- Trigger function for BOTH tables
CREATE FUNCTION set_one_or_two( ) RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $func$
        BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
                INSERT INTO shorthand (shorthand, one_or_two)
                VALUES(new.shorthand, TG_TABLE_NAME)
                        ;
        ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
                UPDATE shorthand SET shorthand = new.shorthand
                WHERE shorthand = old.shorthand
                        ;
        ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
                DELETE FROM shorthand
                WHERE shorthand = old.shorthand
                        ;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
        END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
        ;
        -- Triggers for I/U/D
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER check_one
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON table_one
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_one_or_two ( )
        ;

CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER check_two
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON table_two
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_one_or_two ( )
        ;

        -- Some tests (incomplete)
INSERT INTO table_one (one_id,shorthand,etc_one) VALUES (1, 'one' , 'one' );
INSERT INTO table_two (two_id,shorthand,etc_two) VALUES (1, 'two' , 'two' );

SELECT * FROM shorthand;

\echo this should fail
INSERT INTO table_one (one_id,shorthand,etc_one) VALUES (11, 'two' , 'eleven' );

SELECT * FROM shorthand;

UPDATE table_one SET shorthand = 'eleven' WHERE one_id = 1;
SELECT * FROM shorthand;
```